# How to fix MPI_ERR_RMA_SHARED?

Tags: azure, mpi, shared-memory

I wrote an MPI program in which I use shared memory through MPI_Win_Allocate_shared command, then I run the program on a Virtual Machine with 4 cpus on Azure.
Everything works well with 1 or processes, but it doesn't work with 3 or 4.

I know that MPI_Win_Allocate_shared works only if processes are on the same node, so I thought the problem was related to that. I tried to solve that with an hostfile setting "AzureVM slots=4 max_slots=8", but I still get error.
I'll report the error below:

```
mpiexec -np 3 --hostfile my_host --oversubscribe tables

[AzureVM][[37487,1],1][btl_openib_component.c:652:init_one_port] ibv_query_gid failed (mlx4_0:1, 0)

[AzureVM][[37487,1],0][btl_openib_component.c:652:init_one_port] ibv_query_gid failed (mlx4_0:1, 0)

[AzureVM][[37487,1],2][btl_openib_component.c:652:init_one_port] ibv_query_gid failed (mlx4_0:1, 0)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING: There was an error initializing an OpenFabrics device.

  Local host:   AzureVM
  Local device: mlx4_0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

[AzureVM:01918] 2 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-btl-openib.txt / error in device init
[AzureVM:01918] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages

[AzureVM:1930] *** An error occurred in MPI_Win_allocate_shared
[AzureVM:1930] *** reported by process [2456748033,2]
[AzureVM:1930] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[AzureVM:1930] *** MPI_ERR_RMA_SHARED: Memory cannot be shared
[AzureVM:1930] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[AzureVM:1930] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
[AzureVM:01918] 1 more process has sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt / mpi_errors_are_fatal
Makefile:54: recipe for target 'table' failed
make: *** [table] Error 71
```

Please, could someone explain me how to solve the problem?? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hi, have you solved the problem?
Consider adding these two lines (following the [quide](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/eb/54/An_Introduction_to_MPI-3.pdf))

```cpp
MPI_Comm nodecomm;                                                          
MPI_Comm_split_type(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED, 0, MPI_INFO_NULL, &nodecomm);
```

And after, allocate memory with

```cpp
// define alloc_length (sth like: int alloc_length = 10 * sizeof(int);)
MPI_Win win;
MPI_Win_allocate_shared (alloc_length, 1, info, shmcomm, &mem, &win);
```

I had the same problem (a similar error log at least) and solved it exactly in the way I described above

To better understand, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213745/mpi-3-shared-memory-for-array-struct). I tested the code at the end of the answer chosen as the best one, and unfortunately, it didn't work for me. I modified it as follows:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define ARRAY_LEN 32

int main() {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int * baseptr;
    MPI_Comm nodecomm;
    MPI_Comm_split_type(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED, 0,
            MPI_INFO_NULL, &nodecomm);

    int nodesize, noderank;
    MPI_Comm_size(nodecomm, &nodesize);
    MPI_Comm_rank(nodecomm, &noderank);

    MPI_Win win;
    int size = (noderank == 0)? ARRAY_LEN * sizeof(int) : 0;
    MPI_Win_allocate_shared(size, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL,
            nodecomm, &baseptr, &win);

    if (noderank != 0) {
        MPI_Aint size;
        int disp_unit;
        MPI_Win_shared_query(win, 0, &size, &disp_unit, &baseptr);
    }

    for (int i = noderank; i < ARRAY_LEN; i += nodesize)
        baseptr[i] = noderank;

    MPI_Barrier(nodecomm);

    if (noderank == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodesize; i++)
            printf("%4d", baseptr[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    MPI_Win_free(&win);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Now, if you name the code above as `test.cpp`
`mpic++ test.cpp && mpirun -n 8 ./a.out` will output `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

---

Some right tips I took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912588/can-i-use-mpi-with-shared-memory)

Good luck!