# Is there any way to share variables in MPI?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

TL;DR:
Is there an efficient way to share integer variables over all processes in the standard implementation of MPI (i.e. no libraries or *funny stuff*).

I am working on a simple game AI where we use MPI. The AI uses the standard Alpha-Beta tree search method to find the best move dependent on an evaluation function. The basis of the program works as follows:

1. board represented as bitboard.
2. process 0 initialises everything by branching the first board based on its number of available moves
3. process 0 distributes work to all of the other processes (e.g. one or more subtrees) by means of MPI_Scatter
4. all processes call an Alpha-Beta search on their subtree which then creates a larger tree for that process
5. each process calculates a static evaluation of their tree
6. use MPI_Gather to find the best move
7. return the best move.

I have two problems:

1. Dynamic load distribution/ balancing:
   Some processes have more work to do than others. For example, if there are fewer moves to make in one set of trees it will complete faster. But what if a process could determine that it was under heavy load and could benefit from some load sharing with another process that is empty? A simple idea is to maybe implement some sort of queue where processes can ask for work? Is this possible without a shared queue amongst the processes? The problem with gathering the evaluation of each process' deepest board is that the total runtime is essentially that of the slowest process. Thus, if P1 takes 0.1s to calculate its evaluation but P2 takes 10s to calculate its evaluation, and say P1's evaluation is better, there is wasted computation and time.
2. Shared Alpha-Beta values:
   Alpha-Beta values determine a tree's cut off depth. This means, that even if another process has found better Alpha-Beta values than another process, that other process with outdated Alpha-Beta values would benefit from using the other process' Alpha-Beta values instead. Is there any way to share these two values without extreme communication overhead?

I read this on another post:

> Each thread gets a stack, while there's typically only one heap for the application (although it isn't uncommon to have multiple heaps for different types of allocation).

Is this applicable to MPI? Is there some sort of heap that can be accessed by all processes? Am I confusing the terms thread and processes?

Some other solutions I have thought about:

- Process 0 acts ONLY as a communicator between processes and manages a queue. Processes are to evaluate smaller depth values, send their best tree to P0 and request work. This would also solve the problem of Alpha-Beta sharing. Unfortunately, I think that this would still result in long wait times as P0 will have to wait for each process to return their best tree in order to reevaluate the queue. Furthermore, we lose an entire process (P0) to act only as a communicator and thus, not doing much work.

Any opinions would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Each MPI rank is it's own process. Each MPI rank (process) can have multiple threads. A memory location can be accessed by all of the MPI ranks by using one sided communication (chapter 11 in the MPI 3.1 standard), but you should be even more aware of raced conditions when using it.

Comment: You can share data between MPI processes on the same node using MPI_Win_allocate_shared and access it like normal memory using direct read/write (i.e. you do not need to call MPI_Get/Put). However, this will not work across a network, i.e. all processes need to be running on the same computer under the same OS instance. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912588/can-i-use-mpi-with-shared-memory/39914018#39914018